# Why DFS doesn't check children of a node, that was chosen for development, for a goal state

Tags: algorithm, search, time, time-complexity, depth-first-search

Sorry if my grammar is far from being perfect, English is not my native language.

If i understand correctly, DFS does a goal test for a node only if it was chosen for development and not while it's been generated.
It seem odd to me because after DFS chooses a node for development, it adds all of the node's children to the open list anyway. while doing so, why not check whether one of its children is a goal state, and if this is the case, DFS can return a solution and terminate? Keep searching in deeper layers after generating a goal state seems to be a huge waste of time, am i wrong?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, of course you can do that as you want. DFS, BFS are just a way of searching, so you can implement it as you want. There's no limit or strict template of it :D

Comment: Yet, I thought that there must be a reason for writing the classic DFS in the way it was written. The time waste seems obvious, so I was wondering if I'm missing the purpose of applying the goal test as the DFS applies it... And thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not wrong, of course if you find the destination in current node's neighbors (children in your wordings), you can terminate it.

However, I will stick to "standard" implementation due to 2 reasons: (Just my personal concerns)

1. **Easier Implementation, Higher Readability**, For example, you may want to do something when you reach destination, then in standard way vs your way, the pseudo code is like

```js
//The way I like to implement
void dfs(int x){
  if(x is destination){
     do_something(); return;
  }
  mark x visited
  foreach x's unvisited neighbor{
      dfs(x's neighbor)
  }
}
          
//The way you suggest to implement
void dfs(int x){
  mark x visited
  foreach x's unvisited neighbor{
      if(x's neighbor is destination){
         do_something(); return;
      }
      dfs(x's neighbor)
  }
}
```

I simply think that as DFS is based on recursion, and per my understanding, put the base case checking at the first place of the function by moving it out from the FOR loop is a more "recursion-like" implementation.

Also if do_something() is rather a complex task, the code may become messy if you put the checking and handling in the For loop (Readability concern)

2. **Time Complexity is the same** You are correct that it may save many recursion level, depends on the order of node transverse.

   However, does the time saved worth to give up the readability mentioned above?  I do not think so.

   As the time complexity is the same, as long as each node is visited at most once, the complexity is **O(N+M) where N is # of nodes & M is # of edges**

   So it is **not worth** to risk writing some messy codes to save the negligible time in general speaking.